# Date transformation in time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, data-analysis

I have a month column which has values such as 202212, 202103, 201901. The entry 202212 means, December 2022.
I want to transform all the month column in the dataset to date for example 202212 should become 01-12-2022, 202103 become 01-03-2021 an so on.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"d":["202212","202103","201901"]})
df['d2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d'],format='%Y%m')
print(df)
```

output:

```
        d         d2
0  202212 2022-12-01
1  202103 2021-03-01
2  201901 2019-01-01
```

Explanation: both `pandas.to_datetime` and `datetime.datetime.strptime` does assume first day of month if it is not given, example showing such behavior of latter:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("202212","%Y%m")
print(d.year, d.month, d.day)  # 2022 12 1
```

Comment: I already have a column 'd' as 'Number' with million of records.  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Number']),format='%Y%m') is giving me error that pd cannot assign to function call.

Comment: @VISHALVYAS `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Number']),format='%Y%m')` format is named argument for pd.to_datetime, you should not put `)` immediately after `df['Number']`

Comment: Great! It worked